# How can I set a conditional lambda function in python to take different group sample sizes?

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, group-by, sample

(Edited) Spinoff of a previous question. If I have a datafame with two groups, 0 and 1, how can I select a sample of 50% of the rows associated with one group (0), and 100% of the rows associated with the other group (1)? This is the code so far. The conditional lambda clause is not working as is. Thanks in advance.

```
grouped = df1.groupby(['group'], as_index=False)
newgroups=grouped.apply(lambda x: x.sample(frac=0.5) if 'group' == 0 else x.sample(frac=1.0))
```

What I have now:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['billy', 1, 0, 1], ['bob', 0, 1, 1], ['sam', 1, 1, 0], ['sally', 0, 1, 0]], columns=['name', 'group', 'feature_a', 'feature_b'])
```

I would like this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['billy', 1, 0, 1], ['bob', 0, 1, 1], ['sam', 1, 1, 0]], columns=['name', 'group', 'feature_a', 'feature_b'])
```

OR this:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['billy', 1, 0, 1], ['sam', 1, 1, 0], ['sally', 0, 1, 0]], columns=['name', 'group', 'feature_a', 'feature_b'])
```

Comment: if you post a reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that''ll help in contributors in answering the question.

Comment: I tried to post the sample. Not sure how to indent it to turn it into a table though.